# Magento 2 Guest Checkout Not Working

Tags: magento-2.1, guest-checkout

I have installed fresh magento 2.1.6. When I click Go to checkout I get the popup to register. I am not able to proceed as guest.

My configuration is set Yes for allow guest Checkout.

```
Stores > Configuration > Sales > Checkout > Checkout Options
```

Why can I proceed as a guest and place an order ?

Comment: Do you try magento default checkout or third party extension?

Comment: Default checkout. I have no third party extension installed.

Comment: @userpk Just try with enable all cache and check.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have not added a Downloadable/virtual products in your cart.